# Diferença de horas entre duas datas com php

Tags: php

Preciso com `php` comparar 2 datas e verificar se o intervalo  delas já são maior que 1 hora:

Uma ideia mais ou menos so pra compreender melhor:

OBS: Preciso das Hora Minutos e Segundos!

```
<?php 

    $data_atual = "09-10-2018 20:00:00";
    $data_passada = "09-10-2018 19:00:00";

    if ($data_atual > $data_passada){
        echo "Faz mais de 1 hora entre as datas";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Na vd preciso das horas e minutos e segundos... mais a ideia é essa ai  preciso so das horas

Comment: Pessoal Resolvido !